# GoogleMaps : Return is Not working in Reverse Geocoading

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, return, return-value, anonymous-function

I am trying ReverseGeCoding its working but i cant get return value

```
function reverseGeoCode(lat,lng) {
 var reverseGeoAddress = '';
 var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
 var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
 geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
     if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
         if (results[1]) {
             if(results[1].formatted_address.length){
                 reverseGeoAddress = results[1].formatted_address;
                 //NOTE: when i console.log(reverseGeoAddress );
                 //its working fine i am getting the address
                 return reverseGeoAddress;
                   //but return not working.

             }  
         }
      } 
  });
}
```

when i call my function like

```
   var address = reverseGeoCode(31.518945,74.349316);
```

now every time my address variable is "undefined";
why is this doing so??
Any hint ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function `reverseGeoCode` is not having any return value

```
return reverseGeoAddress; is inside anonymous function.
```

Simple fix would be - you can possibly use callback since it is asynchronous function. "callback" can be a handler from the place you invoke.

```
// Invoking reverseGeoCode....
reverseGeoCode(lat,lng, function(myAddress){ 
  // Your custom code goes here...
});

function reverseGeoCode(lat,lng, callback) {
var reverseGeoAddress = '';
 var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
 var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
 geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
     if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
         if (results[1]) {
             if(results[1].formatted_address.length){
                 reverseGeoAddress = results[1].formatted_address;
                 // Callback the handler if it exists here
                 // No return value
                 callback(reverseGeoAddress);
             }  
         }
      } 
  });
}
```